# Add column with yesterday sale information on a daily sales database

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a database that contains daily sales information of different products and stores.

```
StoreSku  Date         UnitsSale
 A-2134   20/04/2019      2
 A-2135   20/04/2019      1
 A-2134   19/04/2019      5
 A-2134   18/04/2019      3
 A-2135   19/04/2019      6
```

i want to add a column with  one day ago unit sales information

```
StoreSku  Date         UnitsSale    OneDaySales
 A-2134   20/04/2019      2             5
 A-2135   20/04/2019      1             6
 A-2134   19/04/2019      5             3
 A-2134   18/04/2019      3            NULL
 A-2135   19/04/2019      6            NULL
```

i've got to be honest, i don't know if sql is able to achieve this. If not, could you please recommend a way? considering there are over thousands of records.

Comment: i have a litle bit of freedom when it comes to the database engine: Could be mysql, spark sql, microsoft sql, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       lag(UnitsSale) over (partition by StoreSku order by Date) as prev_unitsSale      
from t;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `left join` with date arithmetic.  That varies by database, but the standard would be:

```
select t.*, tprev.UnitsSale as prev_unitssale
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.StoreSku = t.StoreSku and
        tprev.Date = t.date - interval '1 day';
```

These are not exactly equivalent.  The first will get the previous day in the data.  The second will get the previous day -- with `NULL` for the day after missing days.

Comment: Both queries are great, but i'm going with the second one as there are days when some products don't have sales. Can you please elaborate a little more in the second query? i don't understand how you get the data for tprev table, and i'm getting many rows with "null" in all  its columns, so i thinks it has something to do with the join sentence.

Comment: @BenJ. . . . That is probably the day after a day when all the stores are closed -- such as a holiday.

Comment: if that was the case, only theprev_unitssale would be Null, not the whole row, right?

Comment: It's not working:
    |A-1102767|02-12-2018|  2|          null| 
    |A-1102767|03-12-2018|  1|          null|

Comment: @BenJ. . . . You would only get `NULL`s in the columns associated with the first table in the `LEFT JOIN` if the values are `NULL` in the table itself.